# How to know the height of the text contained in JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I already used `getPreferredSize()`, `getSize()`, `getMaximumSize()`, and `getMinimumSize()`. But none of them give me an accurate height of the text in the `JTextArea`.

```
JTextArea txt = new JTextArea();
txt.setColumns(20);
txt.setLineWrap(true);
txt.setRows(1);
txt.setToolTipText("");
txt.setWrapStyleWord(true);
txt.setAutoscrolls(false);
txt.setBorder(null);
txt.setText("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.");
add(txt, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(30, 40, 540, -1));
JOptionPane.ShowMessageDialog(null, txt.getPreferredSize().height);
```

Comment: Could you please provide the code that you use. The problem on this topic is usually happen when you getSize() before these have actual size for example you call getSize before it render or call pack() or set visible on the root container. Another reason is the size is change by the layout you use.

Comment: Don't use  a null layout or AbsoluteLayout.  Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. Post an [mre] demonstrating your problem.

Comment: (1-) This question can't be answered because the OP has not provided the full context of the question. See the OP's last question for full context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68003700/how-to-resize-jtextarea-so-it-could-fit-all-text-in-it-and-make-the-jpanel-form

Comment: @camickr Ah im sorry, im new here... Thank you for pointing out the best way to post. Also thank you for your answer too, that's helping me to find the answer today. I already changed my layout manager not null or absolute again, but using box layout. And for getting the height of the jTextarea, im calculating it manually because my width is constant value so i could calculate it using the logic of the George below.

Comment: @progprog *for getting the height of the jTextarea, im calculating it manually* - how?   Your question asks how to calculate the height of the text, not the text area itself. You don't know how many lines there will be in the text area because of wrapping of the text. The solution provided by George only calculates the height of the text area itself, not of the text. *Also thank you for your answer too,* - well you should reply where the suggestion was given so that other who read the question/suggestion know it provided some help.

Comment: @progprog You can get the height of the text in a single statement. But I guess that is not your requirement. Since you haven't posted an [mre] and clarified your requirement based on my comment above.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

(If I understood your question)

Just take the number of lines that exist on the textArea and the height of each line and multiply them:

An example:

```
public class ProductsFrame extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(ProductsFrame::runExample);
    }

    private static void runExample() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(10, 10);

        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        frame.add(new JScrollPane(textArea));

        textArea.addCaretListener(e -> {
            int linesWithText = textArea.getLineCount();
            int heightOfEachLine = textArea.getFontMetrics(textArea.getFont()).getHeight();

            int heightOfText = linesWithText * heightOfEachLine;

            System.out.println("TEXt HEIGHT:" + heightOfText);
            System.out.println("TEXT AREA HEIGHT:" + textArea.getSize().height);
        });

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the OP hasn't learned how to ask a question with all the required information needed to solve a problem. Check out the OP's previous question for context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68003700/how-to-resize-jtextarea-so-it-could-fit-all-text-in-it-and-make-the-jpanel-form. This won't work because line wrapping is not done until the component is actually displayed so we won't know what the actual number of lines are until then. Once the text area is visible we can just use the getPreferredSize() method.

Comment: @camickr Well, I did not know when OP wants to get the height. If OP wants the height when the textarea is visible, my answer works. But it was my assumption. I will wait for OP's feedback. If it does not work for him, I will delete my answer. Plus, if OP uses `null` layout, I assume he/she has problems with placing it, which means the textArea is not visible, which means my answer won't work.

Comment: @GeorgeZ. thank you for your answer, i could find my logic how to calculate height from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found `textArea.getPreferredScrollableViewportSize()` very helpful - it contains the area that the textfield would need to fully display without scrolling.